# My simple map project doesn't get & show my location in simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, mkmapview, ios-simulator, xcode7

I am using XCode v7.2.1, Simulator v9.2 .

I have a UIViewController which shows a map & is supposed to get my location & show it on map:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            map.showsUserLocation = true
        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

}
```

I have added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in **info.plist** as shown below:

[image]

I have also selected the Debug -> Location -> Custom Location ... and set the longitude & latitude of Helsinki, Finland as shown below:
[image]

When I run my app, the map is shown, **however it doesn't get my location**. Why? (I mean I don't see the blue point in anywhere of the map).

===== UPDATE ====

I also tried [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html) when my app is running, however it doesn't help either.

Comment: You should set `showsUserLocation = true` anyway, not by condition

Comment: I want to ask user's permission first then show location. Anyhow, nothing wrong with my conditional code either.

Comment: Consider the following situation: user opens controller, agree to use location, you perform `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` but after that nothing happens, there is no more code to show location on map so user will see blue point only next time he opens this controller

Comment: But the problem is the simulator doesn't pop up the dialog asking for user's permission either. The locationManager doesn't work at all, that's my question waiting for an answer.

Comment: Could you add `delegate` to `locationManager` and look what happens in delegate methods?

Comment: ==> In your AppName-Info.plist have Added a new row with the key name being:
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
OR
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: @Akash, I don't have that file. I am using XCode V7.2.1 , I only have info.plist & as I said in my post, I have already added that key value.

Comment: @Leem.fin I can give you my code of map but it is in objective c. tell me if you want that.

Answer (score 7):

you are requesting the user's location, but not actually doing anything with the response. become the delegate of the location manager and respond to the authorization change.

this code works for me on 7.2.1 (after selecting "Apple" in Debug -> Location):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            map.showsUserLocation = true
        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        guard status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse else { print("not enabled"); return }
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}
```

Comment: If we are updating the userlocation in delegate. Why we need to update the location in viewwillappear too? Is it necessary? If yes,can you please explain me?  I'm new to iOS development,please help me.

Comment: in viewDidAppear there are two branches. A) if the user HAS already authorized the app to view their location, then IMMEDIATELY start showing the location on the map. B) if the user has NOT authorized the app to view their location, then ask for permission and if granted THEN show the location on the map

Answer (score 0):

I agree with   @Casey 's answer,but sometimes you need to do a little more with `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
       //reset mapView's center in case your custom location was wrong.
        map.centerCoordinate = location.coordinate
       //mannual call show annotations to avoid some bugs
        map.showAnnotations(map.annotations, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add

```
locationManager.delegate = self
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```